# Should dbatools be installed on all SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

I'm looking to leverage dbatools powershell module for our SQL Server management needs.  The install process does not lend itself for installation across a large number of servers.  Is it really necessary or even a best practice to install dbatools across all SQL Servers in the environment or leverage a server we use for our database management as a central place to install to and manage from there?  Seems like a lot of the commands I've looked at can be used remotely.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general you should be able to use most of the dbatools functionality from your laptop (or whatever host you use to connect to your server via SSMS). If you're the kind of admin who prefers to RDP onto your servers and use SSMS locally, then maybe try to break that bad habit; but in general you should be able to use dbatools alongside the rest of your administrative toolset.

If you've never used powershell at all in your environment before, then you may need to coordinate with your sysadmins or networking team to debug some PS Remoting  growing pains or open up ports here and there. As well, if you want to use dbatools functions as a part of SQL Server Agent Jobs, you will need to install (and upgrade!) dbatools locally (or in a way that the module can be loaded by the agent). I recommend [this guidance](https://wsmelton.github.io/dbatools-sql-agent/)

And as always - for any specific issues, the [SQL Community dbatools slack channel](https://app.slack.com/client/T1LTZ0BQV/C1M2WEASG) is the bee's knees.

Comment: I think this nails down what I was thinking.  I did see info on using remoting and will discuss it with sysadmin team.  I think this shows the idea that more planning is needed to understand how we want to integrate it in our environment.  Than you for your answer

Comment: The dbatools is a very powerful one for your job centralization.